# Selenium RC test passes when it should fail on verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("string"))

Tags: selenium-rc

I have a suite of Selenium tests that I created in the Selenium IDE and ported over to Java. In several tests I use the Java equivalent of the `verifyTextPresent` command to confirm some text on the page (`verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent())`).

I found an spelling error in the text on the page when running the test from the IDE, but the error was not caught when running the test via Selenium RC/TestNG. Here's an example of the code that I have and the text that is causing the problem (spelling error in bold):

**Text:**

Please correct the errors indicated below.

You need to add **a** least one restriction.

**IDE:**

```
verifyTextPresent | Please correct the errors indicated below.
verifyTextPresent | You need to add at least one restriction.
```

**Java:**

```
verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Please correct the errors indicated below."));
verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("You need to add at least one restriction."));
```

Since both versions of the test have the correct text, why is the Selenium RC version not catching the error? Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that the test continues to run after the call to `verifyTrue()`. Verifications in Selenium catch the exceptions that would be thrown by a failed verification, as opposed to an assertion which throws an exception and causes the test to fail. Because verifications catch exceptions instead of throwing them, the test passes.

At the end of the test, the method `checkForVerificationErrors()` needs to be called to see if any of the verifications failed. If the method is not called, any verification errors will be ignored and the test will still pass (absent any other problems).

A discussion on the Selenium Google Group about the error itself is [here](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/541ad52e299b9abd/2003b55459c86715?lnk=gst&q=selenium+rc+verifyTrue#2003b55459c86715). A discussion about the various verifications vs. assertions is [here.](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/91e8d91596bf001f/b466e58bf2028742?lnk=gst&q=selenium+rc+verifyTrue#b466e58bf2028742)

Comment: Works a treat.  It seems a nifty feature too.  Not throwing an assertion exception until the method is called.  I do this immediately after calling selenium.stop to ensure a clean close.

Comment: Great post, we just had  freak out when we realized that verifyTrue(false); didn't fail the test that was running. We have hundreds of tests that calls this without the checkForVerificationErrors(); call. We've fixed the issue in our tearDown() method, now I just have to re-run the tests....

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem... My workaround is to use assertTrue() instead of verifyTrue(). I hope it works for you to.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround; I had thought of this too. I'm guessing there is some kind of bug in Selenium RC; I'll have to check out the source later to see if I can find it. It also may be that it won't get fixed due to the move to WebDriver in 2.0, but I have to use this for the time being until 2.0 is out of beta.